# Extracting variables from dict and saving to csv

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I want to extract certain variables from a dict and save them in a `csv` (sometimes, the variable `key` I am looking for might not exist. I am new to working with dicts, so I am not sure how to handle this).

I am using the code below, which works, but somehow prints each character of the extracted variable to a new column (instead of all characters of the value in 1 cell).

Also, I am not sure how it behaves when it does not find the key. Any suggesstions would be greatly appreciated:

```
with open('20181122_1300_Token_test.csv','a',encoding='utf-8') as f:
    w = csv.writer(f, delimiter=";", lineterminator='\n')
    w.writerow(data.get('name'))
    #w.writerow(data.values())
```

Comment: please post sample input and expected output!!

Comment: use `w.writerow([data.get('name')])` See examples here https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.writer

Comment: @r_black: works perfectly, thank you!

Comment: so you want to have single cell per line? That's really strange (and you don't need to use csv module for that)

Answer (score 0):

writerow method expects iterable and because string is iterable of single letters, it writes your word split by each character

You probably want to use csv.DictWriter instead of csv.writer - at https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter you can see documentation along with simple example

(main difference: to writerow you'll pass whole dict instead of single value from it, also you'll need to provide fieldnames parameter - to determine order of columns)

Comment: DictWriter is suitable for list of dicts, but not to `extract certain variables from a dict and save them in a csv`, unless you want to get one long row :)

Comment: I know that, but from her example and description it seems that she wants to have a part of dict on one row (he doesn't give example on other rows, so I'm assuming that she probably wants to have same part of other dict on other row. Otherwise it would mean that she has some really strange data model.)

Comment: Variables from same dict in columns of the same row, same variables from other (similar) dict on following rows. r_black's method worked for me so I am going with that. Thank you!